# R: Slicing matrix on rows and columns with conditional statements

Tags: r, matrix

With the matrix:

```
C = matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=2, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
```

How do I select a submatrix of `C` according to the conditions that rows must have a with a mean greater than two, and columns must have a mean between 2 and 5.

Result should be the middle column of matrix `C`.

I'm imagining two boolean vectors (one for column condition, and one for row condition) that can be combined into a boolean matrix.  That boolean matrix can then be used to select the submatrix from `C`.  Is this correct, and if so, how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C[rowMeans(C) > 2, colMeans(C) > 2 & colMeans(C) < 5, drop = FALSE]
#     [,1]
#[1,]    4
#[2,]    5
```

Comment: gosh darn that was easy.  Didn't realize you could put boolean expressions right into the matrix indicies...